# convert utc datetime into diffrent timezone datetime

Tags: java

Below program gives output: `Sat Dec 18 15:53:33 GMT+05:30 2021` but i am expecting it should give time by adding `+5:30` in time , i need to covert this  `Sat Dec 18 15:53:33` into "Asia/Kolkata" timezone value. how to do it!

```
Date date1 = null;

try {
    SimpleDateFormat isoFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");//.parse(p.getCreatedDate());
    isoFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata"));
    date1=isoFormat.parse("2021-12-18 15:53:33"); 
    System.out.println(date1);

    Log.e("------------xxx1------",date1.toString());//prints // Sat Dec 18 15:53:33 GMT+05:30 2021
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Do not longer use the outdated `java.util.Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` use the modern `java.time` API

Comment: @Jens ok. could you please answer the question, it will help me

Answer (score 1):

## Avoid legacy classes

Never use `SimpleDateFormat`, `TimeZone`, `Date`, `Calendar`, etc.

Use only *java.time* classes.

## *java.time*

Your input string nearly complies with ISO 8601 standard format. Replace SPACE within `T` to fully comply.

```
String input = "2021-12-18 15:53:33".replace( " " , "T" ) ;
```

Your input has no indicator of time zone. So parse as a `LocalDateTime`.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input ) ;
```

Specify your desired time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ;
```

Place your date-with-time into the context of a time zone.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( z ) ;
```

Now you have determined a moment, a point in the time line.

Generate text representing that moment.

```
String output = zdt.toString() ;
```

To see that same moment in UTC, an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds from the prime meridian, extract an `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;
String output2= instant.toString() ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 isoFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata"));
 date1=isoFormat.parse("2021-12-18 15:53:33");
```

You've set the formatter to a particular timezone, so strings that do not specify a timezone are interpreted relative to the timezone of the formatter.

```
 System.out.println(date1);
```

And then you format it according to the timezone of the Date, which is the local timezone.  So I conclude your local timezone is in fact GMT+05:30.  You parsed a time relative to the same timezone you used to print it.

---

Given these particular Java classes, which are not necessarily the best way (see the answer from Basil Bourque), here's what I think you're trying to achieve.

```
    // parse time as if in Z timezone
    SimpleDateFormat isoFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date date1 = isoFormat.parse("2021-12-18 15:53:33 Z"); 

    // print date as if in some other timezone
    SimpleDateFormat locFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z");
    locFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata"));
    System.out.println(locFormat.format(date1));
```

Output is

```
    2021-12-18 21:23:33 +0530
```

You might need to explicitly set the isoFormat timezone to GMT, though I don't think so.

Comment: I want the `Sat Dec 18 15:53:33 GMT+05:30 2021` into like this `Sat Dec 18 21:12:44` something like this, converted to GMT+5:30